# question(s) regarding iterating through an instance created with resig's simple js inheritance script

Tags: javascript, inheritance, iteration

i've been trying to learn as much as i can about js inheritance over the past week, and ran into john resig's simple js inheritance script. everything has been going fine while testing the code, until i tried to iterate over one of my extended objects. here's the code:

```
var Person = Class.create({
    init : function(sex, devStage) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.devStage = devStage || "newBorn";
    },
    Sex : function(val) {
        if (val) { this.sex = val }
        else { return this.sex; }
    },
    DevStage : function(val) {
        if (val) { this.devStage = val; }
        else { return this.devStage; }
    }
});
var person = new Person("male");

var Mike = Person.extend({
    init : function(sex, devStage, name, age) {
        this._super(sex, devStage);
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    },
    DevStage : function(val) {
        if (val) { this._super(val); }
        else { return this._super(); }
    },
    Name : function(val) {
        if (val) { this.name = val; }
        else { return this.name; }
    },
    Age : function(val) {
        if (val) { this.age = val; }
        else { return this.age; }
    }
});

var mike = new Mike("male", "adult", "Mike", 38);

for (var k in mike) {
    if (mike.hasOwnProperty(k)) { console.log("mike.hasOwnProperty(k) = " + k); }
} //only "sex", "devStage", "name" and "age" show up as properties in firebug's console
```

i was expecting the "DevStage", "Name" and "Age" function properties to exist on the mike object, but it seems as though the only properties making it onto instances of each object are those being sent into the init function. the other properties are on the object's prototype, and work fine, i just can't find them using the hasOwnProperty method. i've read most every comment on resig's blog post where the script is published, but i couldn't find anything relating to this issue.

my question is whether or not this is normal? i can see times where this would be a problem if doing some property checks between objects. does this seem like a valid worry on my part? while not totally new to js, i'm certainly no seasoned pro, so ANY feedback on my current situation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. The properties `DevStage`, `Name`, `Age` and `init` are attached to `Mike`'s **prototype**, which the new object `mike` **merely points to** - the properties are not copied over when the object is created with `new Mike()`.

As such, `mike` does not have those properties as **"own properties"** - they are accessible only by looking at `mike`'s internal prototype property (which is what the JS engine does automatically when accessing properties: `mike.DevStage`). Some JS engines, such as Chrome's, expose this internal prototype property as `__proto__` which you can examine.

This is a depiction of how `mike` is represented internally:

```
mike = {
    __proto__: { // Internal pointer to the prototype, for Mike
        init: function () {},
        DevStage: function () {},
        Name: function () {},
        Age: function () {},
        __proto__: { // The prototype's prototype, for Person
            init: function () {},
            Sex: function () {},
            DevStage: function () {}

            // Ultimately, the prototype will point to Object.prototype
            __proto__: {...}
        }
    },

    // Own properties
    name: ...,
    age: ...,
    sex: ...,
    devStage: ...
}
```

If you remove the `if (mike.hasOwnProperty(k))` condition from the loop, then you will see the other properties as well.

Comment: wow...i think i got a little whoosy from all the studying =) i totally forgot about the object returned from the "new" call. in most of my coding i'm using singletons, so it's been awhile since i've instantiated with new.  thanks so much for the quick answer with the great explanation!!